If $y$ is a quadratic irrational, then there exists $M > 0$ such that $\forall p, q$, $q > 0$, $\left| \frac{p}{q} - y \right| > \frac{M}{q^2}$.
Suppose $y$ is a quadratic irrational. I want to show that there exists $M>0$ such that for all $p, q$, $q>0$,
$$\left| \frac{p}{q} - y \right| > \frac{M}{q^2}.$$
I'd like a reminder on how to do this. Say $y=[a_0, a_1, ...]$ is the continued fraction expansion with $p_n, q_n$ defined as usual. I tried using the facts

The continued fraction of $y$ is periodic, hence bounded

For $q < q_n$, $\left|\frac{p}{q} - y \right| > \left|\frac{p_n}{q_n} - y \right|$ (i.e. the continued fraction's approximant is the best)

$\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n} - y \right| \leq \frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}}$


Then if the $a_i$s are bounded, say $\max_i a_i = a$, then we can write $\frac{1}{q_n q_{n+1}} \leq \frac{1}{aq_n^2 + q_{n}q_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{aq_n^2}$. Set $M = \frac{1}{a}$ and we are done.
But some of the inequalities are backwards in showing this result - particularly in the third fact, disallowing us chaining them together. I've forgotten how this is done, can someone please show where I've gone wrong and correct the proof?

You don't need the apparatus of continued fractions to show a lower bound, in the case of quadratic irrationals. I wrote an answer, a bit long:  what matters is there is a binary quadratic form with a "minimum"  integer value; then that the same form factors when the irrational roots are thrown in. I should check Cusick and Flahive...

This is a particular case of the Liouville's Lemma.

Good; Khinchin's little book, theorem 27 on page 45. https://archive.org/details/khinchin-continued-fractions/page/44/mode/2up

The thing that quadratic irrational gives you is this:  your irrational, call it $r,$  is one of the roots of $Ar^2 + Br +C,$   where $A,B,C$ are integers,   next $ \delta^2 = B^2  - 4AC >0,$   while this quantity is not a perfect square, that is $\delta$ is itself irrational.
Call the roots $r,s.$  name  $r = \frac{-B + \delta}{2A}$  while  $s = \frac{-B - \delta}{2A}.$
Note $|r-s| = \frac{\delta}{|A|}.$
We make an integer quadratic form $$ A x^2 + B xy + C y^2.$$
As $\delta$  is irrational, for $x,y$ not both zero,
$$ |A x^2 + B xy + C y^2| \; \geq 1 \; \; .$$
At the same time, the form factors using $\delta.$
$$ |A||x-ry | |x-sy | \geq 1 $$
Divide through by $y^2$
$$ |A| |\frac{x}{y} - r|  |\frac{x}{y} - s| \geq \frac{1}{y^2} $$
Finally, let us demand that the convergent $x/y$  be close  enough to $r,$  in this form:   require $|\frac{x}{y} - r| < \frac{\delta}{|A|}.$ We note
$  \frac{x}{y} - s  =     (\frac{x}{y} - r)   + (r-s)$   Thus
$ |\frac{x}{y} - s| < \frac{2\delta}{|A|}.$  or
$\frac{2\delta}{|A|}  >  |\frac{x}{y} - s| $
From $ |A| |\frac{x}{y} - r|  |\frac{x}{y} - s| \geq \frac{1}{y^2} $   we reach
$$ |A| |\frac{x}{y} - r|  \frac{2\delta}{|A|} > |A| |\frac{x}{y} - r|  |\frac{x}{y} - s| \geq \frac{1}{y^2} $$
or
$$ 2 \delta  |\frac{x}{y} - r| >\frac{1}{y^2}$$
so that
$$   |\frac{x}{y} - r| >\frac{1}{2 \delta y^2}$$
Reminder:  we demanded that the rational approximation be closer to $r$  than the (fixed) distance between the roots, called $r,s.$  We are demanding $|\frac{x}{y} - r| < \frac{\delta}{|A|}.$  Now that I think of it, a poor approximation proves itself:  if $|\frac{x}{y} - r|  \geq \frac{\delta}{|A|}$   then $|\frac{x}{y} - r|  \geq \frac{\delta}{|A|y^2}$
